# Syntax error before string constant

Tags: c, string

I am seeing "syntax error before string constant at line '  testFunction(45, UP),'"

```
#define UP   "UP\0"
#define DOWN "DOWN\0"

#define testFunction(intensity, direction) \
    { \
      .force        = intensity, \
      .direction    = direction, \
    }

struct configureObject {
  int   force;
  char direction[7];
```

};

```
static const struct configureObject configureFiles[] =
{
  testFunction(45, UP),
  testFunction(46, DOWN),
};
```

in main()

```
    printf("force: %d\n", configureFiles[0].force);
    printf("direction: %s\n", configureFiles[0].direction);        

    printf("force: %d\n", configureFiles[1].force);
    printf("direction: %s\n", configureFiles[1].direction);
```

There are no other compiler hints. What may be the reason for this error?
Thank you.

Comment: Look at the generated C program output *after* the CPP runs (and thus after the macro expansion and replacements takes place). The flag used will vary depending upon compiler. (Also, normally string literals don't include a manual `"\0"`.)

Comment: noteworthy. I will jot this down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `direction` for two different things in:

```
.direction    = direction,
```

Both get substituted.

Try:

```
#define testFunction(intensity, dir) \
    { \
      .force        = intensity, \
      .direction    = dir, \
    }
```

(This is just an illustration, there's probably a better name than `dir`.)

Comment: This, Sir ... is perfect.